# how to hide columns in ssrs expression

Tags: hide

I have dataset called fields including 4 columns called Employee, Grade, Country, and All Hours in the table, the ability is if I select Employee in the filter should show only Employee and All Hours remaining Grade and Country should hide in the output, please help me to get the correct output Thanks in advance.

[current report output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQ4A4.png)